# How to pass a C string into a Zig function expecting a Zig string?

Tags: c, zig

Trying to use a Zig library expecting a string... but I get a string buffer from a C library.

That means that I need to pass a value of type `[*c]u8` to a function that accepts `[:0]const u8`.

How to do that?

I found this way so far:

```
const buffer: [*c]u8 = callC();
const str = std.mem.span(@ptrCast([*:0]const u8, buffer));
```

Which looks more complicated than it should (and makes a copy??).

The Zig docs says that:

> String literals are const pointers
> to null-terminated arrays of u8.

So I thought they are compatible C strings and a very simple cast like `@as([*:0]const u8, buffer)` should suffice?

Comment: I might be wrong, but: `@ptrCast([*:0]const u8, buffer)` should suffice. But why use pointers when you can use wonderful slices? Then just `std.mem.span(buffer)`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Which looks more complicated than it should (and makes a copy??).
>
> So I thought they are compatible C strings and a very simple cast like @as([*:0]const u8, buffer) should suffice?

The issue here is that there is a difference between `[*:0]u8` and `[:0]u8`

- `[*:0]u8` is a pointer with an unknown size ending in a `0`. To determine its length, you have to loop over it and find where it ends.
- `[:0]u8` is a slice containing a pointer and a length. You can think of it like `struct {ptr: [*:0]u8, len: usize}`. This allows code using it to immediately know its length without having to loop over it.

`@pointerCast` is not required to convert from a `[*c]u8` to a `[*:0]u8`:

```
const std = @import("std");

test "convert c string to [*:0]u8" {
    const c_string: [*c]const u8 = "some c string";
    const as_ptr: [*:0]const u8 = c_string;
    _ = as_ptr;
}
```

To get a zig-style string slice (`[]const u8` or `[:0]const u8`), you can use the standard library function [std.mem.span](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/blob/1653a9b2597c66cbcc88ea75d8a4b88c163584a5/lib/std/mem.zig#L668-L700)(ptr):

```
const std = @import("std");

test "convert c string to zig string" {
    const c_string: [*c]const u8 = "some c string";
    const as_slice: [:0]const u8 = std.mem.span(c_string);

    try std.testing.expectEqualStrings(as_slice, "some c string");
}
```

---

> ```
> const buffer: [*c]u8 = callC();
> const str = std.mem.span(@ptrCast([*:0]const u8, buffer));
> ```
>
> Which looks more complicated than it should (and makes a copy??).

`std.mem.span` does not make a copy of the string - no standard library function will make a copy of something unless you pass it an allocator.

What it does is counts the length of the string and then returns a slice of the same memory, this time including a length.